# Php, session id control doesnt work?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

here is the code drives me crazy:)

```
<?php
$deger=0;
if (session_id() == '') {
session_start();
$deger=1;
}
else{
$deger=0;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 $counter =$row[2];

if($deger==1){
 $counter--;
}
echo $counter;
?>
```

This basic code drives me crazy. the deger==1 condition always returns true and keeps decrementing the counter. What I would like to do is check the session if the session is new decrement it only once. after that dont decrement the value. Am I missing something here? I am new to php maybe I am missing something.

I look forward to your answers thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to call `session_start();` before any chacks like `if (session_id() == '')` cause theres really nothing in `session_id` when session has not been started. this code i one used is working for me (may be not perfect):

```
session_start();
$user = (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '' ? $_SESSION['user'] : null);
if ($user == null) {
//it's a not logged in user
//checking users credentials and if it's ok
$_SESSION['user'] = $uid; //or whatever you want to use to identify a user
} else {
//it's logged in user
}
```

Comment: Can you just provide a piece of sample code that check whether user first call to a page or old user?

Comment: Thank you very much I think this is the answer What I was looking for. The only  thing I found a bit confusing is that I would like to identify the user with session id which is as far as I know is a unique number. So is that possbile to call this $_SESSION['user'] = session_id();

Comment: in that paticular project i was using `md5($user_name.$user_pass)` as i remember: so i could check this id on evry page

Answer (score 1):

There is always a user session, but not always a php session. So if you did not do a session_start() yet, you can check that with something like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION]['loggedin'])){
    $deger = 0;
} else { 
    $deger = 1;
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
}
```

Wherever you start the session, also fill the $_SESSION var.

Comment: hm... `$_SESSION` is empty if session is not started

Comment: correct, thats what I'm trying to point out here with an isset()

Comment: I copied and paste your code but didnt work. It doesnt show anything ?

Comment: I can only see an empty page when I run this code with echo's.